# Underlying element not clickable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have to render two elements in two different (bootstrap's) rows, the bottom one must be behind the topmost. I can't understand why the underlying one is not catching pointer events.

```css
.smaller-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow
}

.bigger-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 0;
}

.underlay {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row overlay">
  <div class="smaller-square" onclick="alert('yellow');">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row underlay">
  <div class="bigger-square" onclick="alert('green');">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have a `z-index: -1` on the green one which places it behind the `body` and `html` elements.  Your event is probably being captured by the `body`.  Try adding a wrapper and setting a `z-index` on it or applying `z-index` to the container.

```css
.smaller-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow
}

.bigger-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 0;
}

.underlay {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row overlay">
  <div class="smaller-square" onclick="alert('yellow');">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row underlay">
  <div class="bigger-square" onclick="alert('green');">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `position: relative`to the containing element `.container` so that you can apply a stacking context to it by declaring a `z-index` property.

You don't even need the `z-index` property declared on the sibling element `.overlay` since it is not a "positioned element" - which is to say it is positioned `static` and not *absolute* (absolute & fixed) or *relative*. So `z-index` would not apply.

```css
.smaller-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow
}

.bigger-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green
}

.overlay {
/* redundant unless you declare a position property for this element
   that is not "static" - which is the default positioning for any element */
  z-index: 0; 
}

.underlay {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0px;
}


/* Additional */

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row overlay">
    <div class="smaller-square" onclick="alert('yellow');">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row underlay">
    <div class="bigger-square" onclick="alert('green');">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```